# electron in magnetic and electric field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I have this problem where i should find the direction and magnitude of the electric and the magnetic force on the electron. And then I'm supposed to find the direction and magnitude of the acceleration.
E = 1000 N/m
B = 2,5 T
v = 500 m/s

```
X |X X| X
 ¤->
X |X X| X
X |X X| X
  V   V
```

I've found the electric force by Fe = E*q. With direction out of the screen by the right hand rule.
Magnetic force = qvb in the y direction (meaning up) by the right hand rule. 
Now Im supposed to find the acceleration but I'm a bit stuck here. What i'm struggling with is to combine the two forces on the electron.  Can someone get me in the right direction?

Comment: Am I missing something? Don't you just add the two forces (vector addition) to get a total force $\mathbf F$ then use $\mathbf F = m \mathbf a$?

Comment: So F = Fm + Fe?

Comment: Using vector addition, yes. It isn't obvious from your diagram what the direction of $\mathbf E$ is.

Comment: it's down. The answer made sense. Guess i was lost in my head a moment there. Thanks for the simple but valuable input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use vector addition and Newton's Second Law. For example, if you have
$$\overrightarrow{F}_E=qE\hat{x},\space\space\space\overrightarrow{F}_B=qvB\hat{y}$$
then your total force $F_{tot}=F_E+F_B$ is just
$$\overrightarrow{F}_{tot}=qE\hat{x}+qvB\hat{y}$$
Since $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are totally linearly independent, these terms cannot be combined. Then using $F=ma$ you can deduce that 
$$\overrightarrow{a}=\frac{q}{m}(E\hat{x}+vB\hat{y})$$
but if you wanted the **magnitude** of the acceleration, you just take
$$a=\sqrt{\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{a}}=\frac{q}{m}\sqrt{E^2+v^2B^2}$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The force exerted by an electric field is just $\overrightarrow{F}_E=q\overrightarrow{E}$, so if you know the field finding the force is trivial.