# Motion of an electron in a magnetic and electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I have this problem where i should find the direction and magnitude of the electric and the magnetic force on the electron. 
E = 1000 N/C B = 2,5 T v = 500 m/s

```
X |X X| X
  ¤->
X |X X| X
X |X X| X
  V   V
```

I've found the electric force by Fe = E*q. With direction up (negative charge). Magnetic force = qvb which is also in the y direction (meaning up) by the right hand rule.

The question is as follows:

> "the particle will go in constant speed $v$ in $x$-direction without changing direction if the magnetic field is constant but we change the $E$-field. Find the strength of the $E$-field"

Have i determined wrong direction of the Force e? My soloution to this is that i need to change the e-field from positive to negative, so the force of e will cancel out the force of m. Am i on the right track here?

Comment: $F_B=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$. As $q$ is negative it points downward.

Comment: I can't get that right. By the right hand rule :
B pointing into screen (palm faceing into screen) 
Motion in x-direction(index finger). 
Force upwards(thumb)

Comment: You always have to consider the montion in technical current direction (which is from plus to minus) so the direction $q\vec{v}$ is into the negative $x$-direction. You can also first do the problem for a positive particle and get the direction that you first got. And then invert it, because you are actually working with a negative particle.

Comment: ok. Thank you for helping me figuring that out ! 
i now have this equation: F = qvb - Eq = q(E - vb)  which is the lorenz force, right?

 I solve for E and get :  E = (F/q) + vb. 
But in my case the F should be zero right? since it's moving with constant speed in x-dir. So i get E = vb. Correct?

Comment: I was going to suggest you look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252425/electron-in-magnetic-and-electric-field?rq=1 !

Comment: The person has indicated that he was aware of the Lorentz force (in the form ${\bf F} = q ({\bf E} + {\bf v} \times {\bf B}$), Fleming's left and right hand rules and was having problem using the appropriate rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of the force acting on a charge q with velocity ${\bf v}$ moving in a magnetic field ${\bf B}$ is given as ${\bf F} = q {\bf v} \times {\bf B}$. In your question you have ${\bf v} = v {\bf i}$ and the electric field is (eventually) pointing in the direction ${\bf j}$. This means the direction of the magnetic field must be in the ${\bf k}$ direction, since in this case ${\bf v} \times {\bf B} = vB {\bf i}\times{\bf k} = -vB {\bf j}$. You use Fleming's *left* hand rule:

The Thu**M**b represents the direction of **M**otion resulting from the force on the conductor (namely, the direction that the charge is pushed in, *i.e.* the direction of the force).

The **F**irst finger represents the direction of the magnetic **F**ield (taken to be in the direction from North to South).

The Se**C**ond finger represents the direction of the **C**urrent (the direction a positive charge moves).

In the UK we are taught to use the left hand rule for motors (where you have to find the direction of the force acting on a current carrying wire in a magnetic field) because we drive on the left hand side (image taken from Wiki)

[image]

Comment: I think the thumb represents the direction of the force, which is not necessarily the same as the direction of motion.

Comment: "The Thumb represents the direction of Motion *resulting from the force on the conductor*", I think it's understood as the direction the charge is pushed in, namely the direction of the force. Thanks, I will clarify that in the answer.

Comment: Ok, but since i have a negative charge, I inverse the direction so the force is pointing down, right?

Comment: You point your second finger in the direction that a positive charge is moving, so you point your second finger in the opposite direction to which the negative charge is moving. Alternatively, you point your second finger in the direction that the negative charge is  moving and reverse the direction of the force.