# Right Hand Rule on the magnetic field not working?

Tags: magnetic-fields

[image]

- Background: The magnetic field is going into the page and the velocity of the particle is going towards the right.

**What is the sign of the particle?**

I keep getting this wrong. The magnetic field is going inwards so my middle finger is pointed inwards. Then the velocity is towards the right so my index finger is pointed to the right. This makes my thumb go downwards [which is the magnetic force].

But the book says the magnetic force is upwards and not downwards?

Comment: omg, maybe the rhr is broken?!

Comment: wait...what hand are you using for the right hand rule?

Comment: Where in the trajectory are you applying the cross product?

Comment: You use Flemings *Left* Hand rule to calculate the direction of a force on a charge moving in a magnetic field (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This is how your hand should be]

You are probably not using the hand rule correctly i've posted a picture.

Comment: [noise](http://comics.browndailyherald.com/p-branes-and-bosons/files/2014/10/Right-Hand-Rule.png)

Comment: Huh, I didn't know they had a different right-hand rule in India (we use thumb, index, middle for $v$, $B$, $F$). How do you find the magnetic field around a straight wire?

Comment: @knzhou i'm also using the same way you guys use it.

Comment: The hand rule isn't unique. You must define what the fingers represent.  This picture doesn't help without definitions.

Comment: @BillN, the question is pretty explicit about which finger is which.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yeah, I see that now, but, again, the usage is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

> Then the velocity is towards the right so my index finger is pointed to the right.

To apply the right-hand rule, you need to know the *charge* of the particle.  If the charge is -1, like an electron, then the current, $qV$, is in the opposite direction as the velocity and that changes the force from up to down.

Answer (score 0):

You use Flemings *Left* Hand rule to calculate the direction of a force on a charge moving in a magnetic field (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors
and [Motion of an electron in a magnetic and electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253457/motion-of-an-electron-in-a-magnetic-and-electric-field/253506#253506))