# Relationship between Magnetic Field and Electric Field along with velocity and kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, acceleration

I need to understand how the magnitude of the acceleration of a proton will change once it enters a region in where there is a uniform magnetic field and/or electric field?

So, let's say for example that after the proton enters this field, I have an electric field going to the right but I have no magnetic field. In another case lets say that I don't have an electric field but I do have a magnetic field to the right.

My problem is understanding how the magnitude of the acceleration of the proton changes? So, is the magnitude greater in my first case because I have an electric field but not a magnetic field? If somebody will please point me in the right direction to approach this concept.

Example:

Case A : E Field direction=  right &  B Field direction= none

Case B: E field direction= none  &  B filed direction = right

Case C: E field direction= right & B field direction= right

Case D: E field direction= right  & B field direction= left

Comment: What are the forces on the proton? The acceleration is related to the vector sum of these forces by $F=ma$. If the fields are crossed (at right angles) it is best to consider the motion in each direction separately.

Comment: There are no forces? The proton is just entering from the left side with an initial speed that is large. @sammygerbil & not really because in my situation I have the direction fo the electric and magnetic fields. i just need to understand how to find the magnitude of the acceleration of the proton.

Comment: Example:                                                                                                                                  Case A : E Field direction=  right &  B Field direction= none                                                                                     Case B: E field direction= none  &  B filed direction = right                                                Case C: E field direction= right & B field direction= right                                                         Case D: E field direction= right  & B field direction= left  @sammygerbil

Comment: see also [Motion of an electron in a magnetic and electric field](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253457) and [electron in magnetic and electric field](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252425).

Answer (score 0):

In an electrical field, a proton is forced to follow the field lines. Field lines are from + voltage to - voltage and the voltage between forces the proton to - with a force equals to $\vec {F}= Q\vec{E}$ where $Q$ equals to the electric charge of the proton.

In the case of a magnetic field, you have 3 vectors each perpendicular to each other:

[image: Demonstration]

- First one is the field itself.
- The second one is the velocity of the proton.
- Third and final one is the Force applied to the proton

Force is equal to $\vec {F} = Q\vec {v}\vec {B}$.

So depending on the placement of the field and velocity there are some possibilities like accelerating or decelerating but one of the uses is that you can place the fields so that the angle between the forces are 180 degrees. With that setup, you can see that if forces are equal then the proton would continue to move with the same velocity. That makes $Q\vec {v}\vec {B} = Q\vec {E} $.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @EgeKeyvan, what do you mean by setting up the fields so that the angle is 180 between the forces?

Comment: I mean that take a electrical field from west to east and take a magnetic field going inside of the page. When you give velocity to a proton to north,angle between the forces applied to the proton is 180

Comment: Proton does NOT follow the field lines. The _acceleration_ will be along the field lines, but since the proton is a massive particle, if it has velocity perpendicular to the field when entering, or if the field bends, the particle will not follow.

Comment: You are right i am not a native speaker so i made some mistakes explaining the situation proton would have velocity at another axis it wouldnt "follow the lines" what i meant was force will be applied in that direction but i explained it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is proportional to the force. In general, the force on a charged particle is given by

$$\vec{F} = q\left(\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times \vec{B}\right)$$

This tells us that in a purely magnetic field, the proton will not change speed - the acceleration is always at right angles to the velocity, so it will move in a helical path. In a purely electric field, the proton will experience a constant acceleration along the direction of the field lines (note - that doesn't mean it follows the field lines, only that it accelerates in that direction). Whether this causes the proton to speed up or slow down depends on the initial velocity.

The above should allow you to work out your question - the details really depend on the strength of the fields, and the initial velocity of the proton.